# How to fill a rect tag inside an SVG with image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg, rect

I've made several attempts to insert an image inside a `rect` tag inside an SVG, but none of them worked. What I want is when I click on a button there is a function that changes the fill of the `rect`. I tried to use snap.svg but it didn't work either. If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it.

**Code:**

*HTML:*

```
<button onclick="changeRect('rect252')">Input</a>
<object type="image/svg+xml" id="main" class="edit-area"></object>
```

*Javascript:*

```
let objectTag = document.getElementById('main').setAttribute('data', 'image.svg')

function changeRect(id){
    var obj = document.getElementById("main");
    var svgDoc = obj.contentDocument;
    let svgRect = svgDoc.getElementById(id);
    let pattern = Snap().image('teste.svg', 0, 0, 500, 500).pattern(0, 0, 10, 10);
    svgRect.style.setProperty('fill', pattern)
}
```

*SVG:*

```
<rect
   style="fill:#00000;"
   id="rect252"
   width="51.396542"
   height="31.275505"
   x="120.8588"
   y="92.630028"
   inkscape:label="Right"
   visibility="hidden"/>
```

Comment: Your rect has hidden visibility.

Comment: I have the javascript to change it to visible but it shows up in black color